# Model the style (not content) of fonts

Tags: neural-networks, python

I'm looking at creating a model to group similar fonts together. I'm not interested in the content of the fonts (e.g. the words), just the style (thickness of letters, spacing, etc.). My initial idea was to use a similar idea to [style transfer](https://www.kaggle.com/sayakdasgupta/neural-style-transfer-using-vgg19) and just get the style features, then pass that through some scaling, dimensionality reduction (PCA), and clustering (DBSCAN/kmeans) to group the fonts by style.

The majority of my data is just images of a-Z letter from different fonts. However, I noticed in this process that one of my fonts does not follow that pattern (it is an image of a phrase) and was classified as an outlier even though the style of the font is similar to many others.

I would like my model to just look at the style of the font so that if I run inference on any word or phrase, it can determine the font group it belongs to.

Any suggestions about ways where I can get the desired style features of the fonts more accurately?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry, edited to include the specific question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.